# provide an ID to many cells in a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, identity

I have maybe weird question, but it is very important to me to solve this.
I have table which is not with stable amount of rows and columns, so I put the += operator to create cells, rows and etc. Now I need to identify every cell, but I don't understand how I can do it in this situation.

```
function drawBoard(board) {
var t="";
t="<table border: 2px >";
var x,y;
for(x=0; x<board.length; x++){
   t+="<tr>";
   for(y=0; y<board.length; y++){
       t+="<td class='tablecell' onclick=''>X</td>"
   }
   t+="</tr>";
}
t+="</table>";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "need to identify every cell"?

Comment: give id to each of them

Answer (score 1):

By identify a cell I'm assuming you would like to reference them later in different part of the code.

You could achieve it by giving your rows and cells classes and/or ids.

For a row, for example:

```
t += '<tr id="tr-' + x + '">';
```

for a cell

```
t += '<td class="tablecell tr-' + x + ' col-' + y + '" onclick="" id="td-' + x + '-' + y + '">X</td>'
```

Then rows can be referenced by `#tr-x` and cells `#tr-x > td`, and all specific columnd `.col-y`

As  Matheus Avellar mentioned, added id to a cell as well in case you want to reference a particular cell on a grid using `#td-x-y`

Comment: Only using `tr-x` as an ID would make same-row `<td>`'s have the same ID, though. You might wanna use a combination of `x` and `y`

Comment: Just 2 minutes ago I added secondary class `col-y` in case we want to select all columns of specific type, but sure adding additional `id` to create a grid would be useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use:

```
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName('tablecell')
```

Or you can collect every cell on the stage of creation, for example:

```
const cells = [];

for (let i = 0; i <  board.length){
  for (let j = 0; j < board.length){
    const cell = document.createElement('td');
    cells.push(cell);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of each one equal to your 'y' variable.

Something like:

```
function drawBoard(board) {
  var t = "";
  t = "<table border: 2px >";
  var x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
    t += "<tr>";
    for (y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
      t += `<td id="table-${y}" class='tablecell' onclick=''>X</td>`
    }
    t += "</tr>";
  }
  t += "</table>";
}
```

Using a bit of ES6 template literals, you can set tie your ID to your 'Y' variable since it's an incrementing number.

Comment: Only using `y` as an ID would make same-column `<td>`'s have the same ID, though. You might wanna use a combination of `x` and `y`